# From Latitude and Longitude to absolute X, Y coordinates

Tags: geolocation, utm

I have a series of Lat/Long coords. I need to transform it in X, Y coordinates. I've read about UTM, but the problem is that UTM coordinates are relatives to a single zone.

For example, this two coordinates UTM has the same Easting (x) and Northing (y) but different code zone, and so each coords point to a completly different location (one in spain and one in italy):

- [UTM: 33T  292625m E  4641696m N](http://bit.ly/oK3J7i)
- [UTM: 30U  292625m E  4641696m N](http://bit.ly/nOyeeK)

I need a method to automatically transform that relatives coord in absolute X, Y coordinates. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be UTM?  If not, you can also use [Mercator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator%20projection), which is a simpler projection that doesn't rely on zones.

See, for example, [the Bing Maps system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx).

Comment: I think i'll use Mercator, it sounds really simple with acceptable precision.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [ProjNET](http://projnet.codeplex.com/) library.
What you need is to find the WKT (well known text) that defines your projections, and then you should be able to convert between them.

```
       var utm33NCoordinateSystem = CoordinateSystemWktReader.Parse("WKT for correct utm zone") as IProjectedCoordinateSystem;
       var wgs84CoordiateSystem = CoordinateSystemWktReader.Parse(MappingTransforms.WGS84) as IGeographicCoordinateSystem;
       var ctfac = new CoordinateTransformationFactory();
       _etrsToWgsTransformation = ctfac.CreateFromCoordinateSystems(etrs89CoordinateSystem,wgs84CoordiateSystem);

       double[] transform = _etrsToWgsTransformation.MathTransform.Transform(new double[] {  y,x });
```

Note: you have to find the correct WKTs, but that can be found on the project site.

Also you may have to flip the order of the inputs, depending on the transforms.

Answer (score 1):

if we want to correct bearing & Distance in between two points than we use (Polar) method by using Scientific Calculator first of all Press The Button polar than started bracket first
For the Distance POL(N-N,E-E)
For the Bearing  POL(N-N,E-E)RclTan-1 
Now you have got a Correct bearing